# SVN database corruption

Tags: svn

Whenever I try to update my code from the repository I get the message

> Can't open file 'E:\Repositories\Main\db\revs\7\7805': The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

If I try to do a clean checkout it works for a while and then I get the error

> REPORT of '/svn/Main/!svn/me': Could not read chunk size: Secure
>   connection truncated

Strangely I can still check in.

Looking at the db\revs\7 folder there is definitely a few files missing. \6 had all from 6000 to 6999. But in \7 there is 7804 & 7806 but no 7805. There's a few others missing.

Can this data be recreated? I'm fairly certain I should be able to get all except a few recent check ins but I'd much prefer no data loss.

EDIT: Should also note I recently checked a few large binaries into the repository. Does SVN handle their storage in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly why you see what you see, but I'd suggest to check your hard disk first.
Also, check your antivirus log.

Comment: Nothing in my antivirus log, it hasn't been quarantined, no reports of any virus (and I would think if it was a virus the deleted files would be more than just very recent, but not all, checkins). The whole thing screams bug to me.

Comment: Ok. How do you access your repository? Have you tried `svnadmin verify` on it? This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450825/could-not-read-chunk-size-error-in-svn maybe related.

Comment: SVN verify verifies the large majority but then can't find the files at the end.
Strangly svnadmin recover looks for a few hundred revisions past where we ever got to.
I think the best solution is to recreate the repository up to that was verified, then use our local copies to recheck everything in that has happened since